# Package Installer misbehavior

Tags: android

I am unable to understand and fix the following behavior displayed by the Package Installer.

In my application when I press on an "update application" button, I download from a web server un update apk (in case there is) and start the Package Installer afterwards to install the package. Everything goes well and after the installation finishes there is displayed a view with two buttons "open" and "done".

However pressing the "open" button fails to open the installed update as it should, even if the intent to the startup activity is sent  as I observed in logcat. Pressing on menu button and going through the applications installed I am able to find the updated app and start it from here.

What should I do to start the update by pressing open in the final Package Installed view?

Comment: Good question. This happens on an emulator and on a real phone? That behaviour is consistent?

Comment: Is the view with the "open" and "done" buttons created by you? Could you show the code that generates the intent that you are using to invoke the application?

Comment: After about three years, i encounter the same problem, can anybody help me about it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be better to let the Android market place app handle the update process of your app instead of downloading and installing the apk yourself in your app?

Your question doesnt specify why you are doing this, if you have a specific reason, do update your question and i will try to have another look.

regards